# Inequality with $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, inequality, permutations

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_{2m}$ be $\{0,1\}$ Bernoulli random variables, i.e. variables which takes values $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. Let $S_m$ be group of all permutations $\pi$ on $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ with uniform distributions. Denote $\|\cdot\|_p=(\int_{S_m}|\cdot|^p d\pi)^{1/p}$.

How to show the following inequality
$$
\|\left(\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i(\pi)-x_{i+m}(\pi))^2\right)^{1/2}\|_p\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^m\|x_i(\pi)-x_{i+m}(\pi)\|_p^2\right)^{1/2}
$$